# My system is allowing duplicates- could the cause be a delay in MySQL writes?

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a problem with my web application that I've built.
It takes and processes customer orders through a web service.

Now, it does a check of MySQL to make sure this order hasn't been processed before, but lately, we have been getting some duplicates. The time between these two orders is 1 millisecond apart.

I know this is my application and I should know this, but it is more of a generic question:

Is it possible that the 1 millisecond difference could be the difference between MySQL writing a record to its database, and my application checking for that record? If MySQL was taking this time to write its record, I can see that it would be possible for 2 duplicate orders to sneak through.

It appears that it is allowing duplicates because it is checking if the order already exists, and determines that it doesnt.

If so- are there any better ways of preventing duplicates from coming into my system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check whether the order exists and conditionally insert it in a single transaction.

If you first perform a SELECT and separately an INSERT, you leave a window open where the same INSERT can happen.

If you use a unique index on a field that makes your orders unique (e.g. Order ID), the second attempt to insert the same data would fail in a manner that you could gracefully handle.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. At the moment, the process takes around 2 seconds to complete. The uniqueness check is at the start of the process, and the inserting of the data is at the end of the process. So that delay between the start and the end must be where the order is sneaking in. I might do 1 or 2 things: add a primary key somewhere, and move a check right before the inserting of data.

Comment: Even if you move the check right before inserting data, there is still room for this problem to happen.  The room is just much smaller.  I suggest that you place your SELECT/INSERT in a transaction.  If the whole processing step takes 2 seconds, you want to do the SELECT/INSERT at the end if possible. Leaving a transaction open for 2 seconds, while not usually fatal, is not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Can you please explain how transactions would help here? You mention about creating a unique index- unfortunately I can't enforce uniqueness in the DB as not all customers want uniqueness.. It's more of a business rule. Secondly, it is legit for the same order to appear more than once in the table.. Just one of the records will have an 'ordered' date against it and the others will not. There should only be 1 order with the same ID that has an ordered date